# Castle ActiveProject retrieving stale data from FindAllByProperty

Tags: c#, .net, activerecord, nhibernate, castle-activerecord

I have an older WinForms 4.x application which is using Castle.ActiveRecord 3.0.0 RC (which is I think the latest available version) on top of NHibernate 3.1.0.4000 (which is not the latest but it was current at that time).

I've noticed an odd data inconsistency behaviour inside one form.  It creates a `TransactionScope` for the lifetime of the form and doesn't commit it until the end.  It fetches a list of objects and provides some editing UI for them.  One of those is a checkbox for the `IsPrimary` boolean property.

Only one object is supposed to have `IsPrimary` == true, so when you toggle the checkbox it does:

```
var others = MyData.FindAllByProperty("IsPrimary", true)
        .Where(x => x.Name != current.Name).ToList();
foreach (var data in others)
{
    data.IsPrimary = false;
    data.Save();
}
current.IsPrimary = true;
current.Save();
```

(Which probably could be done more efficiently, but ignore that for now.  `current` is the object which is having its checkbox ticked.  And they do all have unique names.)

This works correctly most of the time, but if you open the window, tick the checkbox on some other item (so it does the above and correctly sets the previous one to false), and then without closing the window you try to tick the first item again, you end up with two objects set `IsPrimary`.

The problem appears to be that `FindAllByProperty` is returning the original object state outside of the form's transaction, ignoring any changes.

If I replace the call with this code:

```
var others = MyData.FindAll().Where(x => x.IsPrimary)
        .Where(x => x.Name != current.Name).ToList();
```

Then it returns the correct result (including the changes made inside the form's transaction).

Is this a known bug?  Is there a workaround other than using `FindAll()`?

---

**Edit**: FWIW, using explicit criteria has the same result (it returns stale data, not the correct data):

```
var criteria = DetachedCriteria.For(typeof(MyData))
    .SetResultTransformer(CriteriaSpecification.DistinctRootEntity)
    .Add(Restrictions.Eq("IsPrimary", true))
    .Add(Restrictions.Not(Restrictions.IdEq(current.Id)));
var others = MyData.FindAll(criteria);
// still stale
```

Answer (score 0):

here are playing three things together:

- without commiting the data is not changed inside of the database.
- when possible nhibernate convertes restrictins into SQL and the database-server runs the checks. ONLY if possible.
- a session has a chace and if a record (primary) key is returned that is already in the chace it will ignore the record (values) and just reuse the object from the Cache.

This means Restrictions.Eq("IsPrimary", true) or Where(x => x.IsPrimary) will (I think) run in the database-server and can never see any data only changed in the application (aka. without commit, aka. transient data, aka. dirty data/objects). This means your list of objects you set IsPrimary=false is the worong list if more then one object in your application/session/chace has IsPrimary=true but in the database still IsPrimary=false !

You'd either have to do one of the following things, but all are bad in ther own way:

- load all objects without restriction
- or scann through the sesssion manually to find all transient/dirty objects
- or commit after every Change of IsPrimary

If possible I'd suggest you to switch from a boolean field in the table/class to a refercence field of the type of your data-object in a different table/class with only one entry and stor the primary object in that other table/class. It will automaticaly only allow one primary AND will cause a concurrency if two sessions/users try to create a primary at the same time (better then having two primaris :D ).

Perhaps your data-structure already has a kind of Father/supperior class to your data class and that one should know IT's Primary.

Greetings 
Juy Juka

Comment: Why is the data not in the database, though?  Granted there is still an open transaction, but the changes have been saved, and databases support multiple statements in the same transaction seeing each other's uncommitted changes.

Comment: Hello Miral, NHibernate avoides to send any request to the database as much as possible! (I realy mean that exclamation mark. It realy, realy comunicates with the database as little as possible.) That means (next to other things) that neither an NHibernate-Transaction nor a Save do anything in the database, only the Dispose of an NHibernate-Transaction are sending anthing to the database (within a database-transaction). Greetings Juy Juka

Comment: So, what I'm hearing is that NHibernate is broken and we should avoid using it. :P  (Also despite the :P I'm actually serious about that -- if it has been told about a pending modification but has refused to write it to the database and then returns an incorrect result from a subsequent read within the same transaction -- I can't think what else to call that than "fundamentally broken".)

Comment: Hello, I'm using NHibernate and it is working fine. The trouble is to tell NHibernate exactly what you want. By default NHibernate tries to be as fast as possible, wich means - besides other things - that it will use dirty and transient objects to avoid comunication with the database. You would have to tell NHibernate 1) to commit or 2) write your changes (I don't know how to) or 3) work with the dirty/transient states (you cause them yourself, it's possible). Calling this borken is like caling a db-transaction brocken, because other users can't see uncommited stuff-it's by design.Greetings JJ

Comment: I make a change to some objects.  I Save() those objects.  I then ask for a list of the same objects which satisfy a particular property query.  This is all within the same transaction.  If this doesn't *completely by itself* use the current "dirty" object states within the same transaction, but instead goes and does a database query *and then does not update this with its own internal "dirty" object states*, then this is **fundamentally broken**.

Comment: My point is that the library can choose to ignore my request to save the object state to the database (within an uncommitted transaction) if it likes, but if it does that then it can't get away with returning a different answer than if it had saved it when I asked it to.

Comment: Hello Miral, there is no point in arguing - so I won't. The designers of NHibernate decided to implement it this way and have ther reasons to do so (I can only guess wich, but have a good guess) and it is actually up to them to declare if that is correct or not (of cause they'll say it is correct). You have to account for dirty and transient objects (and I told you some ways how to do so) or not use NHibernate. Greetings Juy Juka